# Datatables - Only allow sorting with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

Is there a way of disabling the column sorting in datatables when clicking on the column header and only allow sorting with the sorting icons (check the red arrow in the picture below)?

[image]

My reason for wanting to disable the sorting is that I am using the headers for column filtering and when you click on the header to enter a string the table sorts by that column (I know it's ugly, but I will change the input box design later).

[image]

I checked their options and could not find anything. I also checked the source code but that was way way way way beyond my knowledge level.

Thanks for any help/suggestion!

/Patrik

Comment: Not sure of the datatables way, but you can cancel the default click action from propagating to the table header from the input.

Comment: add an onclick even on the selectors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Add click event handler for each input in the header and stop event propagation to the DataTables plug-in.

```
$('.filter').on('click', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();    
});
```

**DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uggv6few/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help! It still sorts when I click the column header AND when I click the sort icons though.

Comment: AH, now I see. Just need to expand the filter. Let me try in my application.

Comment: You sir, are a genious! :)